# TypeError: Cannot add property identity, object is not extensible

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm facing a simple TypeError when I try to prepare my POST body.

Here is my handleSubmit function :

```
const handleSubmit = (values: any, formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<any>) => {
    const prepareBody = { ...values.customerCase};
    if (type === '1') {
      console.log(prepareBody);
      prepareBody.case.identity= {}; // error here even if I remove this line
      prepareBody.case.identity.title =
        values.customerCase.customer.contact.title;
      prepareBody.case.identity.firstName =
        values.customerCase.customer.contact.firstName;
      prepareBody.case.identity.lastName =
        values.customerCase.customer.contact.lastName ;
      prepareBody.case.type = type;
    }
    PostCustomer({
      reference: props.reference,
      body: prepareBody,
    })
      .unwrap()
      .then(() => {
        formikHelpers.resetForm();
        history.push('/success');
      })
      .catch(() => alertToasts('error', t('toast.error')));
  };
```

I saw many similar issues but didn't find the right answer.
Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: `{...values.customerCase}` creates a shallow copy. `prepareBody.case` is still referring to the original object, which happens to have `preventExtensions()` called. Use [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) instead. (or [lodash.cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) if your minimum target browser version does not support structuredClone)

Comment: @RickyMo Thanks ! I cannot use structuredClone because I have to update NodeJS I guess, but the lodash.cloneDeep function works fine ! Maybe you should post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form values that you're getting from the `formik` library are made [non-extensible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions). When you do `const prepareBody = { ...values.customerCase};` you create an object where a copy of all the [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), however, a reference to non-primitives (like an object) is added, which is why you're not able to extend it.

To be able to modify it, you'll instead need to create a [deep copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Deep_copy) of `values.customerCase`. Javascript standard now provides [structuredClone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) method that'll help you do this.

Comment: Thanks, as I said in an other comment, I have to use lodash.cloneDeep to make a deep copy because my Node version is not up to date, but this works fine !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should declare the object prepareBody in a different way?

```
const prepareBody ={
case: {
    identity: {
        title: null,
        firstName: null,
        lastName: null
    },
    type: null
},
...values.customerCase
```

}

and don't forget to check the properties in the object:

```
values?.customerCase?.customer?.contact?.title
```

or use destructuring:

```
const {
customerCase: {
    customer: {
        contact: {
            title,
            firstName,
            lastName
        }
    }
}
```

} = values || {};